# Svelte value not updating on screen when passing a value to a function

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

A little confused on why the below isn't working. I have tried this where I don't pass an argument to the function and can get the UI to update but if I pass the argument in and do the same exact stuff to it it updates it in the code and I can console.log it out but the UI is not updated.

This Works:

```
<script>
   import { text, toggle_class } from "svelte/internal";

   let line1 = {name:"line 1", display:"some text here", originalText:"some init text", visible:true};

function toggleView(){ 
    line1.visible = !line1.visible;
    if(!line1.visible) line1.display = "*************"
    else line1.display = line1.originalText
};
</script>

<main>
    <button on:click="{toggleView}">{line1.display}</button>
</main>
```

This does NOT work:

```
<script>
   import { text, toggle_class } from "svelte/internal";

   let line1 = {name:"line 1", display:"some text here", originalText:"some init text", visible:true};

function toggleView(field){ 
    field.visible = !field.visible;
    if(!field.visible) field.display = "*************"
    else field.display = field.originalText
};
</script>

<main>
    <button on:click="{toggleView(line1)}">{line1.display}</button>
</main>
```

I think it might be because I'm assigning this to a local variable from Svelte's point of view but I'm not sure how else I would call a function to make this reusable since I would be doing this for a bunch of lines.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

UPDATE - Solved

Below works based on Thomas' answer below:

```
<script>
    import { text, toggle_class } from "svelte/internal";
    var lines = {
        line1: {
            name: "line 1",
            display:"some text here",
            originalText:"some init text",
            visible:true
        }
    };
    
    function toggleView(field) {
        return function() {
            lines[field].visible = !lines[field].visible;
            if (!lines[field].visible) {
                lines[field].display = "*************";
            } else {
                lines[field].display = lines[field].originalText;
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<main>
    <button on:click="{toggleView('line1')}">{lines.line1.display}</button>
</main>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set `on:click` to `toggleView(line1)`, the function is executed right away, just as if you'd set it to `toggleView()` instead of `toggleView` in your other, working example.

You have two ways to fix this. The most common approach is to turn your `on:click` handler into a lambda/anonymous function:

```js
<button on:click="{() => toggleView(line1)}">{line1.display}</button>
```

The other, less common approach is to modify your handler function and turn it into a curried function:

```js
function toggleView(field) {
    return function() { 
        field.visible = !field.visible;
        if(!field.visible) field.display = "*************"
        else field.display = field.originalText
    };
};
```

in which case `on:click={toggleView(field)}` will return a function that will be bound to the click handler, and that function will actually execute when the button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried both options and it still doesn't update. Try this in the Svelte REPL:

<script>
   import { text, toggle_class } from "svelte/internal";
   var line1 = {name:"line 1", display:"some text here", originalText:"some init text", visible:true};

  function toggleView(field) {
    return function() { 
      field.visible = !field.visible;
      if(!field.visible) field.display = "*************"
      else field.display = field.originalText
    };
  };
</script>

<main>
 <button on:click="{() => toggleView(line1)}">{line1.display}</button>
</main>

Comment: You have two different issues: first, you need to pick one approach or the other, but you used both at the same time - it just won't work. Either you use the anonymous handler approach, OR the curried function approach.

Comment: Your second issue is expecting changes to an object property on a copy of the original object to trigger a rerender (and thus update your button text). In order for Svelte to be aware that a rerender is needed, the original object needs to be explicitly updated by being on the left side of an assignment. I've created a REPL with a possible workaround (there are others) here: https://svelte.dev/repl/6356de92fe894ae385c33d80873351e3?version=3.29.4

Comment: I tried doing each one and both and that didn't work but your REPL where you converted it to a lines object with all the lines inside it did the trick. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Here is another approach that I believe is cleaner, using an array for `lines` rather than an object: https://svelte.dev/repl/4a91c14ccb604e61a285a1dd1f849430?version=3.29.4
I've also used the other handler approach in order to illustrate that.

Answer (score 0):

In raw HTML + JS, an inline event handler like `onclick` is actually a bit of code that will be executed when the event happens. In particular, if you use a function in your handler, you must call it:

Example (not Svelte):

```html
<button onclick="toggleView()" />
```

In contrast, in Svelte, a event handler is expected to be *a function*, that will be called when the event happens.

OK because `toggleView` is a function:

```html
<button on:click={toggleView} />
```

Not OK because it calls `toggleView()` every time the markup is rendered (i.e. when reactive vars change), and _the return value of `togggleView()` is bound to the `click` event:

```html
<button on:click={toggleView()} />
```

If you need to pass local arguments to an event handler, then you need to *wrap* the function to still get what you want (that the whole is called when the event happens, not when the markup is rerenred):

Example, OK + argument:

```html
<button on:click={() => toggleView(line1)} />
```

Note that here, the handler is `() => toggleView(line1)`, not `toggleView(line1)`.